# How to install bash on a bitnami/prometheus image?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, debian

I'm trying to use the [bitnami/prometheus](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/prometheus/) container which, according to its documentation, is based on the [minideb](https://github.com/bitnami/minideb) container image which does not have a shell. I would like to install a Bash shell for debugging purposes. I've noticed that this works on the `bitnami/minideb` image directly, i.e. the following Dockerfile,

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:latest
RUN install_packages bash
```

builds successfully:

```
> docker build -t prometheus .
[+] Building 7.8s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                           
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 96B                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest                                                                                                     2.8s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest@sha256:643da48745542c1b8e51a9b79beabc958731c4b539e1fa2261475c69d8e2058e                                               0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest@sha256:643da48745542c1b8e51a9b79beabc958731c4b539e1fa2261475c69d8e2058e                                               0.0s
 => => sha256:643da48745542c1b8e51a9b79beabc958731c4b539e1fa2261475c69d8e2058e 741B / 741B                                                                            0.0s
 => => sha256:aeb2b928697a7e94189f3faf4cf18f3b505a907ab7df55924e763147524c96f6 528B / 528B                                                                            0.0s
 => => sha256:591c594084e5b5c2636b2d41b8626ae3f6624b2b5db93fb6a881a08cc93f14f9 910B / 910B                                                                            0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN install_packages bash                                                                                                                                   4.8s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:9e1a4250e9ff3de115d9f286c904b5aa4da5ba5f0234336a5c22c2d31ce203be                                                                          0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/prometheus                                                                                                                         0.0s
```

However, if I use `bitnami/prometheus` instead of `bitnami/minideb`,

```
FROM bitnami/prometheus:latest
RUN install_packages bash
```

an attempt to build it leads to an error due to a missing directory `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial`:

```
> docker build -t prometheus .
[+] Building 0.4s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                           
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 99B                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/bitnami/prometheus:latest                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/bitnami/prometheus:latest                                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN install_packages bash                                                                                                                             0.3s
------
 > [2/2] RUN install_packages bash:
#5 0.230 E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)
#5 0.230 apt failed, retrying
#5 0.242 E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)
#5 0.243 apt failed, retrying
#5 0.255 E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c install_packages bash]: exit code: 100
```

Any idea how to install Bash on `bitnami/prometheus`?

Comment: `USER root` first ? between thoses lines (dockerfile) : ```FROM bitnami/prometheus:latest
RUN install_packages bash```

Comment: Do you need GNU bash, or will any POSIX `/bin/sh` work?  Looking around [it seems like mindeb already includes bash](https://github.com/bitnami/minideb/blob/master/debootstrap/jessie#L22), are you sure it's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, image bitnami/prometheus already has bash. You can run image bitnami/prometheus with `docker run -d bitnami/prometheus:latest` and get CONTAINER_ID with `docker ps` then check with command

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

If you want to install other packages use following command in Dockerfile

```
FROM bitnami/prometheus:latest
RUN apt install package_name
```

Comment: Another way to enter the shall in a single command is `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash bitnami/prometheus:latest`. (I would note that in `minideb` one uses the `install_packages` command instead of `apt` because the user is not root, see https://github.com/bitnami/minideb).

Comment: Of course. OS of image bitnami/prometheus is Debian, so you have to use `apt` and for image bitnami/minideb it's `install_packages`